# how to search for values in two different collections in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

```
router.post('/api/getproductsbycategory', function(req, res){
var category = req.body.category
Category.getCategoryId(category, function(err, categoryId){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    if(categoryId.length){
        Product.getProductByCid(categoryId[0]._id, function(err, product){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(product)
        })
    }
})
```

});

```
router.post('/api/getproductprice', function(req, res){
var product = req.body.id
Productprice.getProductprice(product, function(err, productprice){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(productprice)
})
```

})

I have some products in one collection and the price is in other collection.when I had inserted product unique id with price but when I call more than one product with their price with forEach loop.At that time the value of the product and price goes different many times.I think this is synchronisation problem.what should I for this??

Comment: Please share your code. Likely to be an issue with the foreach loop.

Comment: I call that both function using Angularjs. can I do something like both product and price  return array of object which I can call on Angular and I dont have to call for @ times from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in one query, if you already have the category the query on Category model is not needed:

```
Product
.aggregate([
        $match: {
            category_id: YOUR_CATEGORY_ID
        },
        $lookup: {
            from: "Productprice",
            localField: "category_id", //category_id field inside Product model
            foreignField: "category_id", //category_id field inside Price model
            as: "price"
        },
    ])
```

Comment: But my both the category, product , and product price are three different collections and I want to  fetch data matching the criteria in 3 of this collections.

Comment: thank u,,,,can you tell me one more thing that how to create schema for both the models?

Comment: My categoryid is in the format of objectID and the this id issaved in the product collection in the form of string like (product_id : "665454g415") something like this.How to match this both values in mongodb console??

Comment: Just match the field _id of the category with field category_id of the product

Comment: How can I use it in nodejs? How to create schema for this?